# How to handle listener failure in AG?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

Availability group has concept of listener that directs the requests to appropriate replica.

So is listener a single point of failure? How to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, the [listener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/availability-group-listener-overview) is a WSFC cluster resource with a dependency on the availability group. It is hosted by the current primary AG node and will move to other nodes of the cluster when the primary role switches, providing high availability.